# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage error

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I get the following error when attempting to call the method below

> The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage

```
public void StartForegroundServiceComapt<SignalRService>(Context context, Bundle args = null)
    where SignalRService : Service
{
    var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(SignalRService));

    if (args != null)
    {
        intent.PutExtras(args);
    }

    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        context.StartService(intent);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Please show the line of code that's giving the error message (you say it's from an attempt to call the method, so likely it's on that line)

Comment: That's entirely normal, the parameters are not of the SignalRService type.  So you have to be explicit about it and type `StartForegroundServiceComapt<Foo>(...);` so the compiler knows you meant the Foo service.

Comment: @Hans Passant ... but of course ... duh ... thanks, just couldn't make the connection.  Not enough coffee ... make this an answer and I'll mark it as such ....